# Azure Search Autocomplete API not working for Fuzzy search

Tags: azure, azure-search-.net-sdk

I have configured azure autocomplete API with all parameters. It gives results for normal keywords but when I tried with misspell keyword then it doesn't provide me expected results. Also, I have added UseFuzzyMatching=true while configuration.
`eg. machine -> gives the expected results. If we try with magine then it provides 0 results from autocomplete API`.

Please let me know if I'm missing any configurations to make `Fuzzy` workable.

[image]

I have data in my index that contains product description and comment fields `'Boormachine'` or `'machine'`, also it provide me result in search API for this.

I have configured suggester while creation of index with the following source fields:

[image: Suggester]

```
Comment, CommentSmall, Description,
ItemBrandDescription, Itemcode, 
ItemGroupDescription,ItemSupplierCode,
SupplierCode
```

[image: Image 1]

[image: Image 2]

We have configured autocomplete API with this:

[image: Autocomepelete code]

as I need to find for keyword suggestions not in group and brand name so excluded these two fields from search fields in configuration.
We can see `fuzzy` related `configuration` in autocomplete with `UseFuzzyMatching` flag. Please let me know if I am missing some configuration to work fuzzy in azure search autocomplete API.

For References click this [Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/autocomplete)

Answer (score 0):

The behavior Azure Search is providing is correct.

Magine is a different term than machine, and probably it does not exist in your index, this is why you're getting 0 results. To enable Fuzzy Search you actually need to append the `~` symbol to the term, so your search will look like:

"search=magine~"

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/query-lucene-syntax#bkmk_fuzzy

Comment: As another option, you can allow the "suggestion (auto complete)" where it will provide results as the user types

Comment: Yes, we have appended tilde operator with distance(i.e. 1 or 2) in search API implementation for fuzzy and it giving us expected results with magine~2 with the same index which we are using for Autocomplete API. But when we applied magine~2 in autocomplete, it doesn't provide expected suggestions.

Comment: magine~2 should work for the real search, about the auto complete (suggester) I am not 100% sure

Comment: Thanks for it, but when I'm searching `magine~2`, `magine~1` the result come look like this please result here  magine~2 https://snipboard.io/g8Fbf3.jpg